# .setTitle() method doesn't change title

Tags: swift, uibutton

I know there are various versions of this question already on stack overflow but none of those could help me. It just won't work

I'm trying to programatically change a UIButtons title here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    semesterTableView.dataSource = self
    semesterTableView.delegate = self

    topView.addShadow(heightOffset: 1)
    bottomView.addShadow(heightOffset: -2.25)
    bottomView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    addButton.setTitle("Test", for: UIControlState.normal) //<--- Here
}
```

As you can see I'm also adding a corner radius to the button what works, therefore the button is indeed connected (
as you can see here:[Proof of connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5x3L.png)
). Just the title change won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your button title set as "attributed" in the storyboard? If so you will need to set the attributedTitle. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624012-setattributedtitle

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! I'm not so experienced in UIKit and I had never heard that an attributed title needed other methods.